# Spanish Language meets Stack Overflow: What is the largest set of consonants that generates Spanish words when any three are taken from it?

Tags: dle, matemáticas

> <sup>This is an attempt to write a new kind of question in which the answer needs to be found by writing an algorithm, rather than searching for it online, posted as [discussed on meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2611/12637). You can take it as a way to improve your programming skills while finding the answer to a curious question about our language.</sup>

---

#### The Spain license plates game

In Spain, current license plates have this pattern:

> 1234 XYZ

where XYZ are three consonants taken from the full set of Spanish consonants (except the 'Ñ', I think).

Sometimes, when traveling with my wife, we used to play a game. When we see a license plate, we take the three consonants and try to form a word that contains those three consonants, appearing in the same order as in the license plate. Examples:

```
BCD
    BoCaDo (valid)
    CaBezaDa (not valid)
FTL
    FaTaL (valid)
    FLeTar (not valid)
FTR
    FleTaR (valid, wins)
    caFeTeRa (valid, loses)
```

The winner is the one who uses the least number of characters, as you can see in the last example.

#### OK, nice game, so what's the problem?

The problem is that not all the combination of consonants allow the game to have a solution, especially when the plate contains consonants such as 'W', 'X', 'Q' and so on.

So here's the question. I would like to find a subset of the Spanish consonants, such that you can take any three consonants (repetitions allowed) from that subset, and always be able to find a valid solution for the game. Example:

```
Subset: {B,C,D}

Possible permutations of these three letters, and some possible words
containing the letters in each permutation in the right order:

    BBB  BaoBaB
    BBC  BarBaCoa
    BBD  BaBaDa
    BCB  BiCarBonato
    BCC  BoCaCalle
    BCD  BoCaDo
    BDB  aBorDaBle
    BDC  aBDuCir
    BDD  BoveDaD
    CBB  CaBeceaBa
    CBC  CaBeCeaba
    CBD  CaBleaDo
    CCB  CabeCeaBa
    CCC  aparCaCoChes
    CCD  CaChaDa
    CDB  abraCaDaBra
    CDC  aComoDaCión
    CDD  aComoDaDo
    DBB  DoBlaBa
    DBC  DeBaCle
    DBD  DoBlaDo
    DCB  DeCasílaBo
    DCC  DeCadenCia
    DCD  DeCaDencia
    DDB  DegraDaBle
    DDC  DeDiCación
    DDD  DefenDeDor
```

Thus, {B,C,D} would be a valid answer, since every permutation of the members of the set (with repetitions allowed) has a solution for the game. But I am looking for the largest set that matches this criterion. What would that subset of consonants be?

---

**Notes:**

1. I don't know if you can download a list of words from the RAE dictionary, so you can use any other Spanish list of words available, as long as it is reasonably complete (see below).
2. Verb conjugations are valid words to be formed, as well as plurals.
3. Note that I am not looking for the solutions to the game, as the game is to be played by humans. I am looking for the largest subset of consonants that allow the game to always be played and solved when taken any three consonants from them (repetitions allowed as seen in the example).

In other words, the challenge consists of finding the largest fair set of letters that the game can safely be played with, such that the players can never get stuck, where "stuck" means they are unable to propose a word for some permutation of letters taken from the alphabet (minus Ñ).

---

**Lists of words:**

1. Public list of words with more than 80K entries (but does not contain plural forms or verb conjugations): https://github.com/javierarce/palabras/blob/master/listado-general.txt
2. Dictionary used in LibreOffice and others: files `es_ANY.dic` and `es_ANY.aff` [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/es). Entries are in the form [word]/[affixes], so you need to decode the way the affixes modify every word. If you want the whole word list generated by these two files, I have uploaded a file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/28bqzpj6mdtucz6/es_ANY.txt?dl=0) (15.9MB, 1,256,499 words).

---

> Posted the actual license plates game [in PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/127047/70347)! :)

Comment: Lista de palabras españolas: https://github.com/javierarce/palabras/blob/master/listado-general.txt No salen los verbos conjugados, pero en total aparecen más de 80 mil entradas.

Comment: I think this would be best done on the programming puzzle SE.

Comment: @guifa I've really thought about it, but I think this would be a problem too complex for what I've seen in [codegolf.se].

Comment: @Carlosalejo it's actually not that complex of a problem, the hardest part is getting the non-default forms of words, but given an aspell or hunspell file with affixes (the Spanish .aff file didn't do double affixes) it's actually pretty simple to brute force it

Comment: @guifa nonetheless, the problems there have all something in common: the final answer is always known, and what is important is the shortness of the code that provides the answer. I don't have the answer here, so I will not be able to validate whose code is the winner.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what are you looking for, code to solve the problem you described, pseudocode, or something else entirely?

Comment: @aparente001 no, I am not asking for code, this is not Stack Overflow nor Programming Puzzles, this is Spanish Language and I am looking for the answer (the best subset of consonants to play the game). The way you find the answer is irrelevant, as long as you find it (an explanation of how you found it will be appreciated). I must say that I am also trying to find the answer, but I am still struggling with the algorithm.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Would question 1 (under Notes) be a good question to pose separately? // Um, if you're having trouble with your algorithm, would you consider posting it, or a link to it?  (Sorry if I'm still not getting it.) // Let's see if I'm starting to understand the question: you want to develop an algorithm that will enable you to find, for ALL permutations of three letters, first, whether there exists a word containing those three letters, without changing the order, and second, of such words that might exist, which one is shortest.  And the letters that get added need not...

Comment: be limited to vowels.  And the word that is found to exist is allowed to be a proper noun (or maybe it is not allowed to be a proper noun).  Is that more or less right?  // It seems to me that part two, the finding of the shortest such word, is by far the easiest part, no?  And the ability to download the list of all words in Spanish is pretty key to the approach one takes?

Comment: @aparente001 the algorithm does not need to find the shortest word with the three consonants selected, that is part of the game to be played by people. The algorithm only needs to find the best subset of consonants that allows the game to have a solution regardless of the three consonants selected from that subset.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Sorry, what is "best" here?  // What subset?  By "subset," do you mean a particular permutation of letters?  // Do you mind if I ask -- I don't know you from Adam -- what sort of math background do you have? // Are you saying that the goal is to identify for which permutations of three letters a word in the dictionary exists which contains those letters (in the correct order)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57902/discussion-between-carlos-alejo-and-aparente001).

Comment: Me han dado en la. Pata de palo. Escribiendo algoritmo ahora. Mismo

Comment: @hlecuanda me vas a tener que. Explicar lo de. La pata de palo. :-)

Comment: Jaja  es una alusión a tu mayor debilidad. Cuando alguien te golpea en tu "pata de palo" figuradamente tu única alternativa es caer en la tentación, como lo haría un hipotético corsario "mocho",* con el suelo, si le propinaras un golpe en su arbórea prótesis... (* alusión a un reciente te tema análogo) jaja

Comment: El problema tiene toda la apariencia de ser NP-completo: se parece bastante a la búsqueda de cliques o coloreo de mapas

Comment: @Rafael optimaciones habrá, por ejemplo, si las combinaciones *BDF* no sirve, no hay porque probar *BCDF*.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Your edits were very helpful. // Please get rid of as many of my proposed edits as you like. // Guys, we really need someone to give us a link to something like a downloadable Scrabble list.  Either that, or a separate question needs to be posed (where can one find such a downloadable list).

Comment: @aparente001 you can use the word list proposed by fedorqui in the first comment. It lacks plurals and verb conjugation, but it is long enough.

Comment: Puedes limpiar un poco el fichero `es_ANY` seleccionando solamente aquellas palabras que contengan al menos tres consonantes: `grep -E '([b-df-hj-ñp-tv-z].*){3}' es_ANY.txt > fichero_algo_mas_limpio` Me descarta unas 15 mil.

Comment: @fedorqui eso lo dejo al criterio de cada uno, que un fichero completo de vocabulario español tampoco viene mal para otros menesteres... ¿Has tenido en cuenta la `ñ` en la expresión regular?

Comment: Errr... ahora sí :) Cambié `j-n` por `j-ñ`.

Comment: @guifa lo mismo se puede decir de la búsqueda de cliques ;)

Comment: @fedorqui eso valdría solo si no hay afijos para dicha palabra.  Es decir, tu método descartaría *izar* a pesar de que *izar* nos da *izando* (ZND) *izamos* (ZMS), e *izasteis* (ZST, ZTS, STS).  Aunque coño, ya tengo creo yo una forma mejor de determinar Paso 1 según mi respuesta.  Esta tarde la pruebo.

Comment: @guifa creo que se refiere a hacer eso en el fichero "descomprimido", es decir, habiendo generado ya todas las combinaciones de palabras más afijos. He subido un fichero así (más de un millón de palabras), tienes el enlace al final del texto de la pregunta.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ya tengo respuesta, aunque la lista expandida tiene fallos (hay muchas líneas que acaban en $| por ejemplo o que tienen / )

Comment: @guifa tienes razón, debe de ser un fallo del programa "unmunch" que usé para generar la lista completa. Acabo de subir una nueva versión corregida.

Comment: Hice pruebas pero no tuve tiempo de juntarlas. Independientemente del _bounty_ (gran respuesta la de guifa) intentaré publicar cuando pueda. Nótese por cierto que tirando del hilo de la referencia de las palabras descubrí que vienen de [lemarios](https://github.com/olea/lemarios): _Proyecto para la confección y publicación abierta de listas de palabras del español_.

Comment: Espero que estén al tanto de la cuenta de Twitter (argentina, principalmente) [LocosXPatentes](https://twitter.com/LocosxPatentes)

Answer (score 4):

Para solucionar este problema, hay varios pasos que tenemos que hacer.

1. Determinar todas las palabras en castellano.  Esta lista es ENORME cuando se tiene en cuenta los verbos (más de 50 formas *antes* de contemplar las numerosas opciones de pronombres enclíticos sobre las *seis* formas imperativas que los admiten).  Estamos hablando de algunos millones de palabras.
2. Determinar (como máximo) !23^3! combinaciones de tres consonantes que pueden formar palabras en castellano según las instrucciones (máximo !23^3!)
3. Determinar cuáles de grupos de 3 a 23 consonantes pueden ordenarse en subgrupos de tres (con repeticiones, así con 3<sup>3</sup> a 23<sup>3</sup> subgrupos cada uno) con tal de que cada de esos subgrupos se incluya en las combinaciones de paso 1.

El problema con que nos enfrentamos es que, teóricamente, habrá [750 cuatrillones](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/es) de subgrupos en paso 3 que tenemos que verificar si están en las combinaciones de paso 2 (que a su vez tiene 12167 posibilidades).

Lo bueno es que tenemos algunas optimaciones que podemos hacer.

Primero, si cualquier letra no funciona en un grupo por sí sola (es decir, *XXX*), podemos descartar aquella letra por completo. (los sufijos hacen posible, teóricamente, *ñoñiño* de *ñoño* o *zarzuelazo* de *zarzuela* pero no usamos Ñ y no sé hasta que punto nuestro diccionario incluye sufijos).  Ello nos reduce a 68588190, muchísimo más calculable.

De las combinaciones en triple, puedo afirmar lo siguiente (usando el regex `A.*A.*A` para pasar el archivo usando una letra en vez de `A`):

```
BBB: posible
CCC: posible
DDD: posible 
FFF: no posible
GGG: no posible 
HHH: posible (5 posibilidades)
JJJ: no posible
KKK: no posible
LLL: posible (1537 posibilidades)
MMM: posible (1593 posibilidades)
NNN: posible (22956 posibilidades)
PPP: posible (8 posibilidades)
QQQ: no posible
RRR: posible (17034 posibilidades)
SSS: posible (58264 posibilidades)
TTT: posible (2354 posibilidades)
VVV: posible (5 posibilidades)
WWW: no posible
XXX: no posible
YYY: no posible
ZZZ: no posible
```

### Paso 1

Para este paso, he tomado dos archivos de [LibreOffice](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/es) (usan el formato Hunspell).  Primero tenemos un diccionario que lleva el format [palabra]/[códigos].  Los códigos son de una letra en el caso del archivo español.  Como ejemplo, tenemos la palabra *hombre/S* y la palabra *mujer/S*.  El código *S* significa que podemos modificar las dos palabras según las reglas del mismo código contenidas en el archivo de afijos.  Estas nos proporcionan las formas *hombres* y *mujeres* (así que tenemos *hombre*, *hombres*, *mujer*, *mujeres*).  CarlosAlejo en los comentarios ya nos ha dado un archivo con todas las posibilidades.

### Paso 2

La forma más rápida, por lo visto, es iterar por cada una de las millón y pico palabras, quitándoles cualquier letra no sea *BCDHLMNPRSTV*.  De allí, determinamos todas las combinaciones de tres de las letras que queda (es decir, con *bbcd* tenemos *bbc*, *bbd*, *bcd*, *bcd*).  Lo bueno es que con perl6 el método *combinations* nos mantiene el orden de las letras, necesario para el problema.

```
use v6;
my @consonants = ; # Ñ is not an option
my $file = open "es_ANY.txt";
my @dic = $file.lines;
close $file;
my %result;
for @dic -> $word {
  %result{.join('')}++ for $word.subst(/<-[bcdhlmnprstv]>/,'',:g).combinations(3);
}
say %result.keys.join(',');
```

El resultado de ello es
`sns,rtb,sph,nnp,mth,clp,tvb,npd,rnt,lll,rhl,tsr,npn,bpc,ssn,hmb,rrm,tvr,snt,dpl,tht,bdl,bsn,lst,bcr,cbr,tvc,lnp,lhc,pcl,llc,dst,srm,ttr,srl,rnp,sdp,hvr,rms,dnn,lvr,rll,prm,psc,lnd,npp,rrd,nrl,dhr,shd,ctm,dtv,rsm,brt,drc,ltc,hch,hhs,hsb,cph,lrv,srs,npb,mrp,nlp,sdl,crl,pcr,pcb,rdl,lpr,cdh,hnn,pls,bvv,hvm,vnt,dhb,lds,dnb,mnr,psd,mln,ndm,hrv,llv,ldb,trd,ptm,lpp,hrp,thn,nvs,dph,vhs,vcn,csn,ndd,vmm,pdb,ttb,mcd,hlh,lnb,lln,vcc,rbd,ldn,bvl,dcp,smh,bpr,hdd,vvs,cnr,hts,bnb,dlv,cpv,pcp,tch,hsl,rtn,cnp,rtr,bvb,src,tpm,svv,hrr,scd,dds,dnm,pss,pch,mnt,tcb,ttc,nvm,dvn,cnn,bns,stt,rsr,rmd,mhv,sct,npl,rht,bbn,ptl,hsv,pvv,rsn,ddm,hcc,hpt,nld,lsr,rsl,mct,mcb,dtc,bmt,rtm,slc,dvp,bct,bdh,vhd,cdc,pnr,pbb,pml,mtc,vlm,bbv,rsv,mpd,vtd,mmv,cnh,dhd,hbv,hnr,clt,rpb,cch,hld,ssp,mhn,tds,lsb,nms,nbt,mlc,stp,pcc,ntc,nsm,lvs,ddc,dbb,rrv,stb,lrm,tlb,mhp,tbn,cnt,tps,mrc,tpn,rlh,vvr,lvp,lph,tdm,ppb,phs,dtm,trn,vbb,hvl,crr,nrt,nmt,tmc,shr,phr,hmp,mtd,mcr,vld,lhh,mhd,snc,vcb,tnl,svd,drp,tdb,rct,cln,vcp,hph,pnp,rvs,brh,cpm,tsc,hpl,msv,rdh,rvr,rvl,htd,hhr,mvb,hrs,lnr,rlv,vrn,ndh,vlr,llp,cnl,rvc,tsd,ltb,phl,rtv,vcr,ptt,vmv,vcv,vdr,vdl,dht,lcb,pbt,msd,lbp,tpd,npv,dcb,dtl,vdn,dpr,mnc,tbc,bhc,cst,cdm,ltm,pnc,psn,nsd,tts,mvs,vnb,rnv,bvt,scl,hls,hnt,nbc,lls,cbc,rpc,lcr,trb,rpt,dth,drh,slr,bsr,svm,lch,vbc,bpb,mnd,bnd,lrn,ddn,phc,lrp,pvh,ttn,ncm,tdl,sbb,ptb,hpb,mht,dls,dbm,lbb,tpv,rnl,lcm,hvd,cmt,nsn,vpb,hpm,pct,lsh,lcp,prs,vmc,ccp,plh,rtl,ths,lnt,snr,rhn,pbc,hmr,vhh,btp,rmc,rtt,tph,lcn,cms,ldv,bds,mrb,sbt,spv,mvr,lvb,lcv,bvs,hnp,psb,nrp,tdp,bcb,tnm,cmd,mnn,rdd,hhh,lhv,bmc,crc,nrc,htr,htm,hcs,cvl,vlt,hvh,dvm,hsn,rvt,tvv,lth,bhs,vdt,tmn,ldr,dsl,cmr,tdt,vpc,sbh,mlm,tdr,btl,hct,pvr,ltp,tvs,cdv,sdv,rrr,spt,prp,pdc,mpl,dpd,dbh,csh,csv,mbv,vrh,nph,smn,btt,rcm,hht,vpt,vsh,rhv,nnl,cls,vnm,pbm,hps,nhr,mdb,ntl,lml,trm,vss,htt,mps,ctl,sdm,nts,dms,bdt,spd,clc,lhl,mmt,lrt,lpm,dlh,mvl,vrl,btv,bps,ssb,dpp,lmp,sbc,cvc,srp,hrd,mlr,cvt,svr,cvn,ncp,tsp,mvc,rnb,rvp,hsr,mnh,vhn,lvt,tcr,nrd,mnb,vdm,cbt,tpc,vbt,pmv,nvl,vvc,mbl,mnm,mvt,pnv,ppt,scn,rmn,vts,lbt,pdd,ddl,vsn,trc,ccr,ddb,bnn,plb,tvd,vnr,rcp,phm,bsb,dvl,ldm,cpt,brn,tlt,vmd,hlm,lpv,thb,nmv,svn,shh,mch,sbn,mvd,vmr,pdl,cdb,drv,bvm,hhd,mbr,ccc,dmh,ptp,,tln,mtm,vnh,lpl,nvr,mmp,rrb,vns,cps,ndl,nml,nbn,rbr,vds,csc,mtv,tdh,vnn,tbv,pvl,drn,bdv,rmp,prt,cml,tcl,rdb,pvs,rmh,bhv,tmp,lpc,hst,hcv,btr,lmm,ptc,tbp,hrh,thc,vbd,tnv,vmn,cbm,dlm,hsh,nvb,rnn,dvv,rpd,drm,prb,crb,rcr,mdc,dvs,dbt,lmt,btm,rbn,mrt,vmt,hbc,rlc,dpt,bsh,vpm,ntr,rbm,rlm,drr,mtr,lrh,pmh,cds,rth,nmn,ndp,vpn,sts,srv,dtr,prd,tml,bpt,vpr,npt,mhb,mns,vvv,bnp,bmd,dcc,hlr,srt,bnl,pnb,dbl,dhv,vvh,pbh,dvh,pdv,hpc,nns,pvp,tnd,nlb,dmb,chn,rbv,ndt,pdn,vbr,rst,prl,svp,nvh,nsl,hpn,clh,vrp,mdm,cdd,spr,lmr,mlp,stl,rhr,vsl,mrl,dcn,lhn,nbv,bsm,dmd,nvc,hdv,hhp,ssm,cbs,dmt,hcm,blp,svc,trs,brp,vnv,dnh,ppm,npc,hmc,cbh,tvp,nhp,tdd,vbn,nmr,mls,rcb,hrl,mss,tnn,nsb,hds,rnd,vrt,hhn,ssr,vnp,hdb,lmn,mtp,nmh,dsn,cdt,snd,mbt,sht,nbr,hvs,shp,phn,nds,mcn,bvr,cbd,hhm,vvp,spp,nhh,pbr,mdl,btb,rdm,mtt,vth,ctv,prc,dhl,bcv,dns,tbr,dmn,crt,ppl,tsv,thd,dsh,dcv,ppd,ntd,lrc,dsv,rlp,tcd,bdm,std,hmt,bvd,pmt,tls,bnr,vrm,psm,dcr,nlm,rdn,msh,csl,snp,dps,drt,vht,pth,ppr,tcn,blr,mbn,tvn,bcc,dnl,tmr,dhp,cbp,ndb,cmm,pcd,ddr,blb,vsm,pnt,mpr,rvh,blv,csb,nhd,nrb,chr,chp,lvc,htl,cnb,dnc,pcv,lnc,ddv,nbm,nlr,npr,hmm,tbm,bmn,dpb,tld,snn,bnc,rss,prh,trh,dbs,rvm,spc,lht,dnv,vlh,tdv,smp,msc,vdd,hhb,pph,slm,rln,hns,brl,nhs,tvt,sdn,rhd,cbn,mbd,dld,tnb,dcs,cll,hnh,lnn,mpn,nll,vpl,srb,sdr,mmc,slb,ccm,mcm,tpp,tnc,lsc,cvm,ppp,btd,bhm,pcn,nsp,vlp,nhl,nmp,pcm,plm,nvt,shm,dhc,tsh,vhl,mdv,lbh,msm,lss,bbm,rsc,dlc,vhr,slt,rbt,hmv,nhc,ntn,chc,sdh,phv,nrv,rrc,mll,slh,ppc,ssd,mtl,srd,pdt,rds,nrs,bcs,cbb,dpc,ctt,svl,htc,nrn,rdc,lbd,mpt,hsd,nvd,nbh,rns,lrb,drl,slv,tcc,mhs,sln,hbs,smr,bbl,nbs,ddd,nsr,bdp,vhm,dtt,ncs,tbb,pvt,bvn,tcs,tms,vtr,dbn,nmb,cvp,snl,brd,chb,vsd,pdh,shs,lvn,tlm,cpr,plv,bch,mvv,mdh,crm,lmv,hsm,mts,ccb,pld,tnp,rvb,sbl,dlb,nhn,dct,bll,hpp,scv,ltt,nvp,cvb,sll,ncc,bhp,pvb,pht,snv,mms,ltd,bhb,lnh,pmp,tnr,trr,scb,tll,rpm,hlt,nmd,bsc,tvl,nrh,mhc,ldt,dcm,pmm,dsb,pbv,pvn,nst,cts,dvr,clb,nct,htb,cmp,shc,ntb,rbh,rvn,pbn,tsb,pnh,thm,ccs,spn,pmc,vtt,pdp,srr,hdn,mbs,sbd,htn,cmc,bcm,stn,cmv,vln,sld,bbd,lvd,vlb,vll,vcl,mmr,bhd,brr,nnc,hlb,dvb,bhh,cnm,tss,dtp,bmb,vcs,bpm,nnh,mhl,bmr,trl,mpv,rcd,vtc,mpc,ctd,rts,vsb,bpd,ldh,crd,rml,mcl,sbp,pmd,lpb,mmh,svb,plp,bcd,vrr,nmc,dhh,mph,vhc,lsv,pnd,hhc,pmr,npm,hpv,tmh,pbl,lhs,msb,vps,vsp,stv,nnr,pnm,sbv,prn,rld,sbm,sst,nnb,lnl,vrs,nnn,hsp,lvh,psv,dtn,php,vsc,hbl,cdp,tcp,mrn,lbn,shv,hmh,ttp,rpp,ndc,csp,bcl,tpt,mbc,lpt,tmb,vmp,nsh,thp,clr,hbd,bcp,lmh,rmv,bnv,brc,vls,ptv,scs,sbs,hcb,hlp,vpv,dlp,dnd,rsd,tpr,dsm,hdm,rcc,rbb,scc,ldp,bpl,rpr,lsm,dmr,nhm,msn,bsp,smb,ssh,phd,sds,mtn,ssv,ccn,lms,ncn,dll,vdc,smv,pds,hln,dpv,nvv,brv,blt,lbm,lhd,vsr,lbv,lnm,rhm,lpn,stm,cct,mvn,lbr,lmb,cvh,pps,cpb,shb,dss,dtd,phb,rmr,mdt,rch,csr,nps,thh,dvt,tlc,bth,tnh,str,dlt,nln,nhv,nbp,rrs,rcs,lvm,hcn,htp,llb,spm,lhb,mhh,mld,btc,dnr,spb,lhm,nnv,hvt,bcn,nnd,plr,hhl,scp,srh,ltn,nrm,tns,clm,nhb,lct,nbl,bst,cpl,tmd,vdb,ccl,cvd,mtb,rph,llt,lhr,shl,lns,hpr,tpl,rbc,ctp,blh,hrm,nss,ncb,mdr,dch,chl,ndv,ltl,llr,hdl,mdn,ncr,mnv,hnv,drb,pvc,mml,rcn,nbd,nht,tlh,bbs,brb,nlt,pcs,tmm,mdp,mbm,sls,hvc,vlv,nnm,tnt,hcp,vvb,ctn,bsl,mdd,tth,hnd,vnd,ctb,rrt,dbr,sms,lbc,vtl,ssl,tsn,ptr,rsh,smt,cdr,bln,dmm,lcc,crh,ncv,dmp,smd,pln,vtp,msp,ttd,dts,ncd,csd,dnp,lsp,prv,msl,rmt,cdl,hll,spl,rdv,mvm,ntm,cvs,tbl,chd,ttl,pms,tdc,rlt,cnd,vms,tbh,ppn,ptd,hnl,rnc,bnt,rrl,dsd,dbd,sdc,dpm,rlr,css,hpd,hnc,ccd,dsc,vvd,ndn,bdd,rdt,dhn,rtd,vvm,hvb,sdb,mrv,lts,lmd,cpp,mmd,tdn,tcv,cmh,rbp,hbr,dln,rtp,cth,mlt,lcs,tmt,sps,hcd,lps,vrv,lld,dnt,cpn,hbt,hbh,mhr,sdd,rps,nsv,trp,tvm,tct,pst,hrt,lbs,bdn,sss,hcr,rpl,trv,rpv,rdp,scr,nlc,bbr,rhs,dpn,vdv,bmh,vch,bbb,bdr,cvv,vmb,tbs,scm,chh,nch,hdp,sdt,tst,mbb,rvd,vnl,mpb,tcm,vcd,tmv,rrh,hss,ltr,lrs,bls,tsm,lrd,mcv,hml,pts,mpm,pvd,hrn,rnm,ntv,brm,dhm,bpp,ldc,ldd,rpn,srn,vbs,vct,bpn,lcl,mnp,dbv,rbs,ncl,vrd,ttv,bht,hmn,tbt,vbl,smc,stc,blm,vcm,hrc,dmv,bvc,rmb,tlv,rls,dvd,rrn,svt,pdr,nvn,snh,sml,cdn,bhr,psr,rrp,mcs,mlv,rnh,bbc,dsr,rtc,mbh,nlv,pbd,dmc,vtb,mrm,pll,rlb,cld,crv,vlc,bmm,crn,csm,hdt,mnl,rnr,rhb,dlr,plc,smm,hms,cnv,htv,bsd,ddt,hcl,vsv,thr,prr,dcl,vdp,ddp,chv,mmn,bml,lnv,vrc,mmb,drs,cmn,cns,cvr,dtb,tpb,hdc,lmc,cbl,ntp,vvl,slp,trt,pnn,msr,crs,hnb,dcd,pmn,mrd,cpd,mhm,rdr,vtm,ppv,bnh,brs,pdm,mlb,snm,rbl,hbm,pns,vvn,snb,llm,lsn,ssc,sbr,hsc,vvt,ttm,nsc,lbl,vbm,tlr,rhp,shn,mcc,hrb,ltv,bsv,crp,nnt,ptn,bmp,clv,llh,dsp,psh,drd,lsd,lrr,svs,rhc,mrh,dml,phh,sth,ndr,psl,mcp,ttt,bld,bbh,vml,lpd,rcv,ddh,hvn,vnc,sch,hnm,dbc,bts,nmm,pmb,rsb,mmm,bhn,nrr,mrr,vpd,mst,vst,cnc,dhs,dvc,nbb,rcl,hbn,mds,psp,nlh,bhl,ctc,mpp,thl,hlc,lsl,nls,hmd,ccv,nth,mrs,lcd,cht,bbt,bms,cbv,bdc,chm,plt,vtn,ntt,lrl,bss,hdr,pvm,ldl,lvv,bbp,rvv,bdb,pnl,vtv,blc,rhh,btn,bnm,chs,rsp,hlv,rmm,tbd,vdh,ctr,tsl,lvl,cmb,vhb,pbs,svh,mlh,cpc,hbb,tlp,vrb`

Estas son las 1701 combinaciones posibles.  Que conste, solo hay 1728 (12<sup>3</sup>) combinaciones dadas las consonantes.  Es decir, hay gran probabilidad de tener 9-10 letras como resultado final.

### Paso 3

Tenemos que formular las combinaciones de entre las letras que sabemos son válidas (por ejemplo, *BCDH*).  Ende necesitamos las combinaciones de tres de esas letras (por ejemplo, *BCD*, *BCH*, *BDH*, *CDH*).  Y de ahí necesitamos las combinaciones, con duplicados, de ellas (*BBB, BBC, BBD, BCB, BCC, BCD…*) que son 27.  Tenemos que probar cada una de estas 27 combinaciones para ver si figuran en la lista que resultó de paso 2.  Si cualquier no aparece, pues podemos descartar aquella combinación de letras al principio del proceso.

```
use v6;
my $former = ""; # insert the comma-delimited string from Paso 2
my %valid;
%valid{$_}++ for $former.split(",");
my @results;
my @consonants = ; # Ñ is not an option
for 3..@consonants.elems {
  SOLUTIONSET:
  for @consonants.combinations($^depth) {
    for $^solutionSet.combinations(3) {
      for ($^three.values,$^three.values,$^three.values).flat.combinations(3).unique {
        next SOLUTIONSET unless %valid{$^combination.join("")}:exists;
      }
    }
    @results.push($^solutionSet.join(""));
  }
}
say @results.join(",");
```

Después de ejecutar este *script*, tenemos la respuesta final:

`bcd,bch,bcl,bcm,bcn,bcr,bcs,bct,bdl,bdm,bdn,bdr,bds,bdt,bhl,bhm,bhn,bhr,bhs,blm,bln,blr,bls,blt,bmn,bmr,bms,bmt,bnr,bns,bnt,brs,brt,bst,cdl,cdm,cdn,cdp,cdr,cds,cdt,cdv,chl,chm,chn,chp,chr,chs,clm,cln,clp,clr,cls,clt,clv,cmn,cmp,cmr,cms,cmt,cmv,cnp,cnr,cns,cnt,cnv,cpr,cps,cpt,crs,crt,crv,cst,csv,ctv,dlm,dln,dlp,dlr,dls,dlt,dlv,dmn,dmp,dmr,dms,dmt,dmv,dnp,dnr,dns,dnt,dnv,dpr,dps,dpt,drs,drt,drv,dst,dsv,dtv,hlm,hln,hlr,hls,hmn,hmp,hmr,hms,hnp,hnr,hns,hpr,hps,hrs,lmn,lmp,lmr,lms,lmt,lmv,lnp,lnr,lns,lnt,lnv,lpr,lps,lpt,lrs,lrt,lrv,lst,lsv,ltv,mnp,mnr,mns,mnt,mnv,mpr,mps,mpt,mrs,mrt,mrv,mst,msv,mtv,npr,nps,npt,nrs,nrt,nrv,nst,nsv,ntv,prs,prt,pst,rst,rsv,rtv,stv,bcdl,bcdm,bcdn,bcdr,bcds,bcdt,bchl,bchm,bchn,bchr,bchs,bclm,bcln,bclr,bcls,bclt,bcmn,bcmr,bcms,bcmt,bcnr,bcns,bcnt,bcrs,bcrt,bcst,bdlm,bdln,bdlr,bdls,bdlt,bdmn,bdmr,bdms,bdmt,bdnr,bdns,bdnt,bdrs,bdrt,bdst,bhlm,bhln,bhlr,bhls,bhmn,bhmr,bhms,bhnr,bhns,bhrs,blmn,blmr,blms,blmt,blnr,blns,blnt,blrs,blrt,blst,bmnr,bmns,bmnt,bmrs,bmrt,bmst,bnrs,bnrt,bnst,brst,cdlm,cdln,cdlp,cdlr,cdls,cdlt,cdlv,cdmn,cdmp,cdmr,cdms,cdmt,cdmv,cdnp,cdnr,cdns,cdnt,cdnv,cdpr,cdps,cdpt,cdrs,cdrt,cdrv,cdst,cdsv,cdtv,chlm,chln,chlr,chls,chmn,chmp,chmr,chms,chnp,chnr,chns,chpr,chps,chrs,clmn,clmp,clmr,clms,clmt,clmv,clnp,clnr,clns,clnt,clnv,clpr,clps,clpt,clrs,clrt,clrv,clst,clsv,cltv,cmnp,cmnr,cmns,cmnt,cmnv,cmpr,cmps,cmpt,cmrs,cmrt,cmrv,cmst,cmsv,cmtv,cnpr,cnps,cnpt,cnrs,cnrt,cnrv,cnst,cnsv,cntv,cprs,cprt,cpst,crst,crsv,crtv,cstv,dlmn,dlmp,dlmr,dlms,dlmt,dlmv,dlnp,dlnr,dlns,dlnt,dlnv,dlpr,dlps,dlpt,dlrs,dlrt,dlrv,dlst,dlsv,dltv,dmnp,dmnr,dmns,dmnt,dmnv,dmpr,dmps,dmpt,dmrs,dmrt,dmrv,dmst,dmsv,dmtv,dnpr,dnps,dnpt,dnrs,dnrt,dnrv,dnst,dnsv,dntv,dprs,dprt,dpst,drst,drsv,drtv,dstv,hlmn,hlmr,hlms,hlnr,hlns,hlrs,hmnp,hmnr,hmns,hmpr,hmps,hmrs,hnpr,hnps,hnrs,hprs,lmnp,lmnr,lmns,lmnt,lmnv,lmpr,lmps,lmpt,lmrs,lmrt,lmrv,lmst,lmsv,lmtv,lnpr,lnps,lnpt,lnrs,lnrt,lnrv,lnst,lnsv,lntv,lprs,lprt,lpst,lrst,lrsv,lrtv,lstv,mnpr,mnps,mnpt,mnrs,mnrt,mnrv,mnst,mnsv,mntv,mprs,mprt,mpst,mrst,mrsv,mrtv,mstv,nprs,nprt,npst,nrst,nrsv,nrtv,nstv,prst,rstv,bcdlm,bcdln,bcdlr,bcdls,bcdlt,bcdmn,bcdmr,bcdms,bcdmt,bcdnr,bcdns,bcdnt,bcdrs,bcdrt,bcdst,bchlm,bchln,bchlr,bchls,bchmn,bchmr,bchms,bchnr,bchns,bchrs,bclmn,bclmr,bclms,bclmt,bclnr,bclns,bclnt,bclrs,bclrt,bclst,bcmnr,bcmns,bcmnt,bcmrs,bcmrt,bcmst,bcnrs,bcnrt,bcnst,bcrst,bdlmn,bdlmr,bdlms,bdlmt,bdlnr,bdlns,bdlnt,bdlrs,bdlrt,bdlst,bdmnr,bdmns,bdmnt,bdmrs,bdmrt,bdmst,bdnrs,bdnrt,bdnst,bdrst,bhlmn,bhlmr,bhlms,bhlnr,bhlns,bhlrs,bhmnr,bhmns,bhmrs,bhnrs,blmnr,blmns,blmnt,blmrs,blmrt,blmst,blnrs,blnrt,blnst,blrst,bmnrs,bmnrt,bmnst,bmrst,bnrst,cdlmn,cdlmp,cdlmr,cdlms,cdlmt,cdlmv,cdlnp,cdlnr,cdlns,cdlnt,cdlnv,cdlpr,cdlps,cdlpt,cdlrs,cdlrt,cdlrv,cdlst,cdlsv,cdltv,cdmnp,cdmnr,cdmns,cdmnt,cdmnv,cdmpr,cdmps,cdmpt,cdmrs,cdmrt,cdmrv,cdmst,cdmsv,cdmtv,cdnpr,cdnps,cdnpt,cdnrs,cdnrt,cdnrv,cdnst,cdnsv,cdntv,cdprs,cdprt,cdpst,cdrst,cdrsv,cdrtv,cdstv,chlmn,chlmr,chlms,chlnr,chlns,chlrs,chmnp,chmnr,chmns,chmpr,chmps,chmrs,chnpr,chnps,chnrs,chprs,clmnp,clmnr,clmns,clmnt,clmnv,clmpr,clmps,clmpt,clmrs,clmrt,clmrv,clmst,clmsv,clmtv,clnpr,clnps,clnpt,clnrs,clnrt,clnrv,clnst,clnsv,clntv,clprs,clprt,clpst,clrst,clrsv,clrtv,clstv,cmnpr,cmnps,cmnpt,cmnrs,cmnrt,cmnrv,cmnst,cmnsv,cmntv,cmprs,cmprt,cmpst,cmrst,cmrsv,cmrtv,cmstv,cnprs,cnprt,cnpst,cnrst,cnrsv,cnrtv,cnstv,cprst,crstv,dlmnp,dlmnr,dlmns,dlmnt,dlmnv,dlmpr,dlmps,dlmpt,dlmrs,dlmrt,dlmrv,dlmst,dlmsv,dlmtv,dlnpr,dlnps,dlnpt,dlnrs,dlnrt,dlnrv,dlnst,dlnsv,dlntv,dlprs,dlprt,dlpst,dlrst,dlrsv,dlrtv,dlstv,dmnpr,dmnps,dmnpt,dmnrs,dmnrt,dmnrv,dmnst,dmnsv,dmntv,dmprs,dmprt,dmpst,dmrst,dmrsv,dmrtv,dmstv,dnprs,dnprt,dnpst,dnrst,dnrsv,dnrtv,dnstv,dprst,drstv,hlmnr,hlmns,hlmrs,hlnrs,hmnpr,hmnps,hmnrs,hmprs,hnprs,lmnpr,lmnps,lmnpt,lmnrs,lmnrt,lmnrv,lmnst,lmnsv,lmntv,lmprs,lmprt,lmpst,lmrst,lmrsv,lmrtv,lmstv,lnprs,lnprt,lnpst,lnrst,lnrsv,lnrtv,lnstv,lprst,lrstv,mnprs,mnprt,mnpst,mnrst,mnrsv,mnrtv,mnstv,mprst,mrstv,nprst,nrstv,bcdlmn,bcdlmr,bcdlms,bcdlmt,bcdlnr,bcdlns,bcdlnt,bcdlrs,bcdlrt,bcdlst,bcdmnr,bcdmns,bcdmnt,bcdmrs,bcdmrt,bcdmst,bcdnrs,bcdnrt,bcdnst,bcdrst,bchlmn,bchlmr,bchlms,bchlnr,bchlns,bchlrs,bchmnr,bchmns,bchmrs,bchnrs,bclmnr,bclmns,bclmnt,bclmrs,bclmrt,bclmst,bclnrs,bclnrt,bclnst,bclrst,bcmnrs,bcmnrt,bcmnst,bcmrst,bcnrst,bdlmnr,bdlmns,bdlmnt,bdlmrs,bdlmrt,bdlmst,bdlnrs,bdlnrt,bdlnst,bdlrst,bdmnrs,bdmnrt,bdmnst,bdmrst,bdnrst,bhlmnr,bhlmns,bhlmrs,bhlnrs,bhmnrs,blmnrs,blmnrt,blmnst,blmrst,blnrst,bmnrst,cdlmnp,cdlmnr,cdlmns,cdlmnt,cdlmnv,cdlmpr,cdlmps,cdlmpt,cdlmrs,cdlmrt,cdlmrv,cdlmst,cdlmsv,cdlmtv,cdlnpr,cdlnps,cdlnpt,cdlnrs,cdlnrt,cdlnrv,cdlnst,cdlnsv,cdlntv,cdlprs,cdlprt,cdlpst,cdlrst,cdlrsv,cdlrtv,cdlstv,cdmnpr,cdmnps,cdmnpt,cdmnrs,cdmnrt,cdmnrv,cdmnst,cdmnsv,cdmntv,cdmprs,cdmprt,cdmpst,cdmrst,cdmrsv,cdmrtv,cdmstv,cdnprs,cdnprt,cdnpst,cdnrst,cdnrsv,cdnrtv,cdnstv,cdprst,cdrstv,chlmnr,chlmns,chlmrs,chlnrs,chmnpr,chmnps,chmnrs,chmprs,chnprs,clmnpr,clmnps,clmnpt,clmnrs,clmnrt,clmnrv,clmnst,clmnsv,clmntv,clmprs,clmprt,clmpst,clmrst,clmrsv,clmrtv,clmstv,clnprs,clnprt,clnpst,clnrst,clnrsv,clnrtv,clnstv,clprst,clrstv,cmnprs,cmnprt,cmnpst,cmnrst,cmnrsv,cmnrtv,cmnstv,cmprst,cmrstv,cnprst,cnrstv,dlmnpr,dlmnps,dlmnpt,dlmnrs,dlmnrt,dlmnrv,dlmnst,dlmnsv,dlmntv,dlmprs,dlmprt,dlmpst,dlmrst,dlmrsv,dlmrtv,dlmstv,dlnprs,dlnprt,dlnpst,dlnrst,dlnrsv,dlnrtv,dlnstv,dlprst,dlrstv,dmnprs,dmnprt,dmnpst,dmnrst,dmnrsv,dmnrtv,dmnstv,dmprst,dmrstv,dnprst,dnrstv,hlmnrs,hmnprs,lmnprs,lmnprt,lmnpst,lmnrst,lmnrsv,lmnrtv,lmnstv,lmprst,lmrstv,lnprst,lnrstv,mnprst,mnrstv,bcdlmnr,bcdlmns,bcdlmnt,bcdlmrs,bcdlmrt,bcdlmst,bcdlnrs,bcdlnrt,bcdlnst,bcdlrst,bcdmnrs,bcdmnrt,bcdmnst,bcdmrst,bcdnrst,bchlmnr,bchlmns,bchlmrs,bchlnrs,bchmnrs,bclmnrs,bclmnrt,bclmnst,bclmrst,bclnrst,bcmnrst,bdlmnrs,bdlmnrt,bdlmnst,bdlmrst,bdlnrst,bdmnrst,bhlmnrs,blmnrst,cdlmnpr,cdlmnps,cdlmnpt,cdlmnrs,cdlmnrt,cdlmnrv,cdlmnst,cdlmnsv,cdlmntv,cdlmprs,cdlmprt,cdlmpst,cdlmrst,cdlmrsv,cdlmrtv,cdlmstv,cdlnprs,cdlnprt,cdlnpst,cdlnrst,cdlnrsv,cdlnrtv,cdlnstv,cdlprst,cdlrstv,cdmnprs,cdmnprt,cdmnpst,cdmnrst,cdmnrsv,cdmnrtv,cdmnstv,cdmprst,cdmrstv,cdnprst,cdnrstv,chlmnrs,chmnprs,clmnprs,clmnprt,clmnpst,clmnrst,clmnrsv,clmnrtv,clmnstv,clmprst,clmrstv,clnprst,clnrstv,cmnprst,cmnrstv,dlmnprs,dlmnprt,dlmnpst,dlmnrst,dlmnrsv,dlmnrtv,dlmnstv,dlmprst,dlmrstv,dlnprst,dlnrstv,dmnprst,dmnrstv,lmnprst,lmnrstv,bcdlmnrs,bcdlmnrt,bcdlmnst,bcdlmrst,bcdlnrst,bcdmnrst,bchlmnrs,bclmnrst,bdlmnrst,cdlmnprs,cdlmnprt,cdlmnpst,cdlmnrst,cdlmnrsv,cdlmnrtv,cdlmnstv,cdlmprst,cdlmrstv,cdlnprst,cdlnrstv,cdmnprst,cdmnrstv,clmnprst,clmnrstv,dlmnprst,dlmnrstv,bcdlmnrst,cdlmnprst,cdlmnrstv`

Como se puede ver, el tamaño de las combinaciones va subiendo (porque empieza con grupos de tres, después de cuatro, etc).  Al final de todo, hay tres grupos con NUEVE letras:

- **B C D L M N R S T**
- **C D L M N P R S T**
- **C D L M N R S T V**

Para los interesados, con 9 letras, hay <sup>9!</sup>/<sub>6!</sub>·3<sup>3</sup> combinaciones posibles (o 13608), cada una de las cuales puede formar una palabra según las reglas.

Comment: Si tienes problemas con tu conjunto de palabras, puedes probar con la [lista de palabras](https://github.com/javierarce/palabras/blob/master/listado-general.txt) enlazada por fedorqui. Son muchas menos, y así al menos probarás el algoritmo. Si consigues que termine en un tiempo aceptable, puedes probar después con una lista más amplia.

Comment: Although, I suppose first I should let it run for BBB/CCC/DDD/FFF/GGG etc.  If any of those fail, I can simply remove them from consideration

Comment: I like your idea of pruning the tree of possibilities in a smart way, at the beginning.

Comment: Tengo mi propio algoritmo desarrollado que me encuentra también un conjunto de 9 letras (creo que es justo el primero de los que tú indicas) cuando lo aplico sobre la lista completa de más de un millón de palabras. Sin embargo, si lo aplico sobre la lista de fedorqui de 80K términos, me encuentra un conjunto de 10 letras, lo cual me extraña dado que es un conjunto mucho más reducido. ¿Te pasa lo mismo?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo todavía no lo he intentado, pero como mencioné, de nuestro conjunto reducido de consonantes había 1728 combinaciones posibles, de las cuales 1701 eran válidas.  Obviamente, si hubiese 1728, la solución sería las 12 consonantes.  De 1701 a 1728 no es mucho, y adicionando un par de palabras que coincidan con las combinaciones inválidas en mi prueba podría hacer la diferencia.  Solo hace falta un sufijo o algo para hacer toda la diferencia (véase el ejemplo de *zarzuelazo* que no figura en nuestra lista y por tanto no tenemos constancia de ZZZ, pero vamos, es plenamente válida)

Comment: He verificado tu solución con otro algoritmo diferente, y es correcta. Y más aún, ya sé por qué la lista de fedorqui de 80K daba una solución con 10 letras. Dicha lista contiene la palabra "gallegoportugués", admitida por la RAE, que permite una combinación con GGG que tú has descartado. Por tanto, para esa lista de 80K palabras las soluciones son "BCDGLMNRST" y "CDGLMNPRST". Si añadimos "gallegoportugués" y sus variantes en femenino y plurales a la lista que tú has usado, la solución pasa a ser "BCDGLMNRST".

Comment: Tengo el placer de otorgarte la recompensa. Una respuesta muy currada y completa (sí, ya puedes quitar el cartel de "trabajo en progreso"). :-)