# Spanish Language meets Skeptics: ¿Ha sido declarada "apapachar" la palabra más bella del español?

Tags: vocabulario, verbos, hispanoamérica, curiosidades

Acabo de ver una imagen donde se habla del verbo *apapachar*, descrito en dicha imagen de la siguiente forma:

> [...] describe el relevante impulso de cuidar, tocar, curar y abrazar con la energía del corazón.

Sin llegar a tanta floritura, el DLE la define como:

> **[apapachar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=34bIlVk)**
>
> Reduplicación de *apachar*.
>
> 1. tr. Hond. y Méx. Dar [apapachos](https://dle.rae.es/?id=34cbJ0w) [palmaditas cariñosas o abrazos] a alguien.

El DAMER, además de proponer una etimología diferente<sup>1</sup>, la describe así y amplía su ámbito de uso:

> **[apapachar](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=apapachar)**. <sub>(Del nahua *papatzoa*, ablandar algo con los dedos).</sub>
>
> 1. tr. *Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, Co, Bo, Ch*. Mimar *una persona* a *alguien*. pop + cult → espon. (**apapuchar**).
> 2. *Mx, Ni, Cu, RD, Ve*. Acariciar *una persona* a *alguien*. pop + cult → espon. (**apapuchar**).

El objetivo de esta pregunta es saber si la última parte del texto de la imagen que vi es cierto:

> [...] ha sido declarada la más bella del castellano.

Buscando por ahí solo he podido encontrar artículos que afirman que "hay quien dice que es la palabra más bella del castellano". Pero claro, yo puedo decir que para mí la palabra *bustrofedón* es la más bella del castellano, y técnicamente sería correcto decir que "ha sido declarada [por mí] la palabra más bella del castellano".

Así pues, ¿existe alguna declaración formal, ya sea por parte de alguna entidad de renombre en el ámbito de la lingüística o por parte de alguna encuesta llevaba a cabo con una muestra poblacional lo suficientemente grande, de que la palabra *apapachar* se haya escogido como "la más bella del castellano"?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>En realidad el DLE dice que *[apachar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=32nSRmM)* viene del náhuatl *patzoa* 'magullar, aplastar', así que en realidad la etimología es la misma, solo que según el DLE la reduplicación tuvo lugar cuando *apachar* ya existía en español, y el DAMER sugiere que la reduplicación tuvo lugar antes, en el nahuátl.</sub>

---

> Otras preguntas de la serie *Spanish Language meets*:
>
> - [Spanish Language meets Stack Overflow: What is the largest set of consonants that generates Spanish words when any three are taken from it?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20685/12637)
> - [Spanish Language meets Parenting: ¿Cómo explicar la diferencia entre "buscar" y "encontrar" a un niño de tres años?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22482/12637)
> - [Spanish Language meets MathOverflow: What is the Spanish Homophonic Group?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27090/what-is-the-spanish-homophonic-group)

Comment: @walen mira, no me acordaba del tag `curiosidades`. De acuerdo con los cambios. Puse `significado`, y de hecho iba a poner `etimología`, porque trato ambos temas en la pregunta, aunque no sea el objetivo final.

Comment: Todos sabemos que la palabra más bonita del castellano es "burbujear" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El Instituto Cervantes, desde 2009 y durante varios años, celebró el ["Día E" o "Día del Español"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_D%C3%ADa_E). Como parte de los actos de los primeros años, se encontraba la elección de una palabra como la favorita, la preferida o la más bonita del idioma español:

- En la edición de 2009, de las palabras candidatas presentadas por más de 73 000 participantes anónimos y tras votación popular, resultó elegida **malevo**.
- En la edición de 2010, y siempre según el Instituto Cervantes, la mayor afluencia de participantes provocó un colapso en sus sistemas, debido al cual decidieron anular la votación y presentar las diez palabras más votadas, pero en orden alfabético en vez de por número de votos: **arrebañar, cachivache, gamusino, infinito, limón, república, sueño, tiquismiquis, titipuchal** y **tragaldabas**. Otras fuentes apuntan a que la votación se anuló porque la ganadora era la palabra "república", y la institución quiso evitar polémicas.
- En la edición de 2011, la votación se restringió a las palabras propuestas por una serie de personalidades del mundo hispanohablante, resultando elegida la palabra **Querétaro**.

Las fuentes para los tres puntos anteriores se pueden consultar en las referencias del propio artículo de Wikipedia.

En años posteriores dejó de celebrarse esta votación, y a día de hoy no tengo claro siquiera si el Instituto Cervantes sigue celebrando el Día del Español (este año tocaría celebrarlo el 22 de junio, es decir dentro de tres días, pero no veo que mencionen el tema en [su portal](https://www.cervantes.es/default.htm)).

Hasta donde he podido ver, ni la RAE, ni la ASALE, ni Fundéu han llevado a cabo votaciones ni eventos similares.
Sí que es cierto que [Fundéu elige anualmente una "palabra del año"](http://www.fundeu.es/palabra-del-anno/), pero no por belleza sino por relevancia. Las elegidas en años anteriores fueron: **microplástico, aporafobia, populismo, selfi, refugiado** y **escrache**.

Por otra parte y ya saliendo de lo que son instituciones "oficiales", en 2015 la organización del evento Hay Festival México junto con BBC World hicieron también una encuesta para encontrar [las palabras más bonitas del castellano](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2015/10/151009_hay_festival_palabras_mas_bonitas_yv). Según el listado que ofrece la web en el texto del artículo, estas son: **sempiterno, mandrágora, cadejo, libertad, anonadado, dulce, arrebol, maquiavélico, conticinio, tiquismiquis** y **escampar**. (No confundir con lo mostrado en la "nube de palabras" de la imagen, que parece estar sacado del evento de Escuela de Escritores descrito más abajo).

Por último pero no por ello más reciente, la web Escuela de Escritores llevó a cabo en 2006, con motivo del Día del Libro, una votación para elegir ["la palabra más bella del castellano"](https://escueladeescritores.com/la-palabra-mas-bella/). La ganadora fue la palabra **amor**. La siguieron, por orden de votos: **libertad, paz, vida, azahar, esperanza, madre, mamá, amistad, libélula, amanecer, alegría, felicidad, armonía, albahaca, susurro, sonrisa, agua, azul, luz, mar, solidaridad, pasión, lapislázuli, mandarina** y **abrazo**.
Lo bueno que tiene esta página en concreto, es que te permite consultar todas las palabras propuestas, aunque no hayan resultado ganadoras. Gracias a eso, podemos ver que, aunque fue propuesta durante la votación, ["**apapachar**" solo recibió tres votos](http://escueladeescritores.com/la-palabra-mas-bella/apapachar-palabra-mas-bella.html); o [cinco, si contamos "**apapacho**"](http://escueladeescritores.com/la-palabra-mas-bella/apapacho-palabra-mas-bella.html).

La cuestión es que todas las encuestas, votaciones y eventos anteriores aparecen como noticias o notas de prensa en multitud de medios como El País, El Mundo, Público, la propia Fundéu, etc. Basta con buscar por `palabra más bella` (o hermosa, o bonita, o preferida) para encontrar las referencias.
Sin embargo, buscando por `palabra más hermosa apapachar` lo único que aparecen son entradas de blogs individuales y publicaciones de Facebook; ningún evento, ninguna encuesta, ni nada "oficial".

Mi conclusión es que **no hay elementos que respalden que la afirmación *"la palabra apapachar ha sido declarada la más bella del castellano"* haya sido hecha por una institución o entidad que tenga un mínimo de relevancia en el mundo de la lengua española**.

Comment: Igual lo que pasó con "república" fue una mezcla de ambas explicaciones: la gente quiso entrar a votar en masa (tal vez solo por el afán de _trolear_, a lo ForoCoches) y acabó colapsando el sistema. :-) Gran investigación, por otra parte.